# Is it correct to say "Est-il possible de te visiter de nouveau" for "Is it possible to meet you again?"

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

I want to ask a question which is “Is it possible to meet you again?”.

For “is it possibleW, I know “est-il possible” is used. My confusion is more on “to visit you again.”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A common informal oral translation would be:

> - Est-ce qu'on peut se revoir ?

Otherwise:

> - Puis-je vous revoir ?
> - Puis-je vous rencontrer de nouveau ?

With "est-il possible", a quite formal way can be:

> - Est-il possible que nous nous rencontrions de nouveau.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "rencontrer" is a good translation of "to meet" in your context.

In your example, "Visiter" would have the additional meaning of going to the place where the person is located (at his/her home), often because the person can't move (e.g. a doctor or a patient at the hospital).

"visiter quelqu'un" is correct, but it will often sound strange (and in some cases a bit "intrusive"). You should rather use "rendre visite à quelqu'un" in this context. This would be :

> Est-il possible de te/vous rendre visite de nouveau ?

Answer (score 1):

Une façon plus correcte serait:
"Serait-il possible de revenir te voir?"
Mais c'est un niveau de langue très soutenu (langue écrite).

Avec des amis, on dira plutôt, "Est-ce que je pourrais revenir te voir?".
D'une manière très informelle on dira: Est-ce que je pourrais repasser?" (sous-entendu "repasser par là pour te voir")

Oublie l'emploi de "visiter", on dira plutôt "Reviens me voir" (Très informel: "Repasse me voir"), de préférence à "rends-moi une visite", qui est beaucoup trop formel.

On dira aussi plus facilement dans le langage courant "Je viendrais te voir", plutôt que "je te rendrais visite". Tout dépend du niveau de langue que l'on cherche.
A une vieille tante qu'on vouvoie, on peut très bien dire "Je vous ferais une visite".